# Мясо свинины или свинина?

Tags: лексика

Правильно ли говорить "мясо свинины", "мясо говядины"? Если мы говорим "мясо птицы", "мясо кроля", то по логике должно быть "мясо свиньи", т.е. - "свинина", и т.д.

Answer (score 7):

Согласна с Вами, "мясо свинины" -избыточное сочетание, получается мясо мяса свиньи. Почему оно появилось? Вероятно, от неграмотности торговых работников,но оно действительно гуляет по Интернету как какой-то профессионализм, а на самом деле - просто ошибка.

Comment: Точно так же, как "мясо говядины" - сплошь и рядом. И "булка хлеба" из этой же оперы.

Comment: Нет,  булка  хлеба  это  сибирский  вариант  буханки  хлеба.  Диалектизм.

Comment: А насколько верно выражение "Заготовка мяса и птицы"?

Comment: >булка хлеба это сибирский вариант буханки хлеба  
  
Если бы только сибирский... Кстати, в моем мире (не в в том, который в тырнете) буханка - это только квадратный хлеб, "кирпич", преимущественно - ржаной.

Answer (score 2):

А "мясо кроля"? Мне кроль известен только как стиль плавания. Или это по аналогии с "курой" - питерским вариантом слова "курица"?

Comment: Cкорее  всего  тоже  питерский  вариант.

Comment: "Кролями" часто называют кроликов те, кто их разводит.
Кстати, "кура" - тоже далеко не только питерский. 
Такое ощущение, что и то и другое прежде всего южнорусское, может даже одесское.

Comment: У меня родители  кролиководы (не любители, а профессионалы с высшим образованием - зоотехник и ветврач). Я знаю, что есть крольчиха и крол (твердо, без Ь). Про крОлей (или, скорее всего, кролЕй) от них не слышала.

Comment: Ну зоотехник и ветврач не обязаны быть кролиководами. Это раз. Во-вторых, я и не утверждал, что так говорят профессионалы - да еще все. Вы знаете, что 99% тех, кто разводит садовую землянику называют её "клубникой", что в корне неверно с биологической точки зрения? Вот здесь, имхо, что-то подобное.

Comment: У зоотехников и ветврачей, как и у всех специалистов, есть своя специализация: коневоды, звероводы, кролиководы...

Comment: >У зоотехников и ветврачей, как и у всех специалистов, есть своя специализация: коневоды, звероводы, кролиководы...  
  
Спасибо, капитан Очевидность!